# What are the geotiff limitations of geotools?

Tags: java, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I'm trying to process [globcover](http://due.esrin.esa.int/page_globcover.php), which is a .tif file of 374mb. Running the following code:

```
File tiffFile = new File("C:\\Users\\CAA\\Desktop\\test.tif");        
GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(tiffFile);        
grid =reader.read(null);
gridData = grid.getRenderedImage().getData(); //row 32
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested region cannot be represented by a single Raster.
at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getData(PlanarImage.java:2163)
at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getData(PlanarImage.java:2016)
at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getData(RenderedOp.java:2266)
at de.myapplication.de.myapplicatoin.GeoTiff.initTif(GeoTiff.java:32)
```

After playing around a bit with QGis and it's Clipper tool i noticed that if i extract a smaller area, the reader works as intended. If i extract huger areas (i.e. entire europe or the entire world) i get the error again. Maybe it's just correlation and not causation, but this leads me to believe that there is somewhere a limit inside the reader. But what is the limit?

As requested the output of gdalinfo for the original tif file.

```
Size is 129600, 55800
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.001388888888900,90.001388888888883)
Pixel Size = (0.002777777777778,-0.002777777777778)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  Authors=Sophie Bontemps <sophie.bontemps@uclouvain.be>,Eric Van Bogaert <eric.vanbogaert@uclouvain.be>,Pierre Defourny <pierre.defourny@uclouvain.be>
  Copyright=Copyright ┬®UCL Geomatics, BELGIUM 1999-2010
  Generate by=gdal_mean
  process begin time=2010-12-23T09:49:37
  process files=CL5_GLOBCOVER-L5_CLASSIF_2009_V2.3.20101220.tif
  process finish time=2010-12-23T09:57:38
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0013889,  90.0013889) (180d 0' 5.00"W, 90d 0' 5.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0013889, -64.9986111) (180d 0' 5.00"W, 64d59'55.00"S)
Upper Right ( 179.9986111,  90.0013889) (179d59'55.00"E, 90d 0' 5.00"N)
Lower Right ( 179.9986111, -64.9986111) (179d59'55.00"E, 64d59'55.00"S)
Center      (  -0.0013889,  12.5013889) (  0d 0' 5.00"W, 12d30' 5.00"N)
Band 1 Block=129600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=11.000 Max=230.000
  Minimum=11.000, Maximum=230.000, Mean=183.164, StdDev=55.663
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=230
    STATISTICS_MEAN=183.16435194952
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=11
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=55.662605157347
```

Comment: can you tell us so more about the tif, what is the output of gdalinfo?

Comment: see my edit for gdalinfo output

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the Java Raster classes used to extract the data from your raster are using an `int` to store the number of cells in the raster. So for you file it is 129600 * 55800 which is 7,231,680,000 which exceeds the Max int (2,147,483,647) so it wraps round to a negative number (-1,358,254,592). The JAI helpfully tells you that you need more than one raster to read out the data in that case, though the message is a little enigmatic.

So you can either select fewer cells at a time for your processing using a smaller envelope

```
gridData = grid.getRenderedImage().getData(new Rectangle(100, 100));
```

or work through the pixels one at a time:

```
GridEnvelope gridRange2D = grid.getGridGeometry().getGridRange();
for(int i=gridRange2D.getLow(0);i<gridRange2D.getHigh(0);i++) {
  for(int j=gridRange2D.getLow(1);j<gridRange2D.getHigh(1);j++) {
      int[] dest = new int[1];
      grid.evaluate(new GridCoordinates2D(i, j), dest );
      System.out.println(i+","+j+"="+dest[0]);
  }
}
```